# Changing alias of ArcSDE feature class?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase, feature-class

I have a feature class. I want to edit the alias. When I go into the Properties of the FC and try to edit the alias, nothing happens. The field will not accept focus and changes are not allowed. How do I change the alias of a feature class? This could be done via code, ArcSDE command line, or through the ArcMap / ArcCatalog UIs.

This is a feature class in an enterprise ArcSDE (Oracle).
The user is the schema owner.
Attempted to change the alias using ArcMap and ArcCatalog.

Comment: Please edit the question to specify the application and context, including whether the connection user is the table owner.

Comment: My first guess is that the table is marked open by another user or process so edit is not available. One of the [sde lock questions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=sde+lock)  might help. I don't know about SDE but it's not uncommon in file-gdb for a person to be locking themselves by having more than one ArcMap session open, or be looking at a feature class item description in the Catalog pane as well as map, and so on. Also check Task Manager process list for ArcMap/Catalog sessions that didn't close properly.

Comment: It's also quite possible that the property is simply uneditable.  Database tables are referenced owner.table or database.owner.table.  No other alias can be accepted by the database, so placing one in GDB metadata could get very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

If the SDE feature has a service running somewhere, you must stop the service to edit the Alias.  After you are done simply restart the service.  You should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have  to unlock the layer and  after  that you can  change the Alias name.

Right click on the FeatureClass -> Manage -> Locks -> On the table right click on the every row and next right  click on the Disconnenct User .
After that I could change  the alias of  the FeatureClass.
[image]